# ssh login my raspberry pi have some WARRANTY

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

When I login to my raspberry pi using ssh, the pi is working well, but it always shows messages as below:

```
Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sun Dec 13 17:06:30 2015 from 192.168.1.110
-bash: LANG: command not found
-bash: LANGUAGE: command not found
-bash: LC_ALL: command not found
-bash: LC_CTYPE: command not found
```

when login,

Could anyone tell me on how to get rid of these messages?.

And I found something in google which i cannot use

What should I do?

Comment: can you cat your .bashrc or .profile on the raspberry ?

Answer (score 1):

When logged in type `locale` and look at the output.

You'll probably see some empty variables such as LC_ALL and LC_MESSAGES etc.

You'll need to assign a certain language code to get rid of this message, for example:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Or

```
export LC_CTYPE="C"
```

This way you'll get rid of the messages for this session.
If you need these changes permanently you'll have to edit your `ssh` client configuration to send these before the shell is being presented.